# What does it mean for a heuristic to be considered admissible?

Tags: search, artificial-intelligence, heuristics

I've been told that an admissible heuristic for a search algorithm is one which never overestimates the shortest path to the goal. However is it valid to have non-goal state nodes have a heuristic value of 0 or is their an additional rule of admissibility that also states that only goal states may have a 0 heuristic value?

For example the shortest path between a node and the goal state D is as follows:

```
A = 5
B = 4
C = 3
D = 0
```

Would the following heuristic be valid:

```
A = 4
B = 4
C = 0
D = 0
```

Would this heuristic also be valid (while also being useless)

```
A = 0
B = 0
C = 0
D = 0
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An admissible heuristic is simply one that, as you said, does not *overestimate* the distance to a goal. It is allowed to *underestimate*, and the two examples you gave are indeed valid, admissible heuristics.

Typically in the kinds of algorithms we're talking about with these heuristics (for instance, A*), it is beneficial if the heuristics are as close to the truth as possible. So, like you already noticed yourself, the last example with heuristic values of 0 for all nodes would not be very useful. Typically you want your heuristic values to be as close to the truth as possible while still being admissible (making sure they **never** overestimate)